# Не отправляется письмо с заказом на почту

Tags: php, mail.ru

Есть форма заказа, которую нужно отправить на почту. Письма приходят на почту хостинга, а нужно что бы приходило на mail.ru. Попыталась поменять адрес почты и письма не приходят, в папках спама тоже нет ничего.

В html скрытые инпуты:

```
<input type="hidden" name="project_name" value="3wit.ru">
<input type="hidden" name="admin_email" value="lianaza@mail.ru">
<input type="hidden" name="form_subject" value="Заявка на кровать">
```

код в mail.php:

```
    $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

//Script Foreach
$c = true;
if ( $method === 'POST' ) {

    $project_name = trim($_POST["project_name"]);
    $admin_email  = trim($_POST["admin_email"]);
    $form_subject = trim($_POST["form_subject"]);



    foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
            $message .= "
            " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
                <td style='padding: 30px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
                <td style='padding: 30px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
            </tr>
            ";
        }
    }} 

    function adopt($text) {
      return '=?UTF-8?B?'.Base64_encode($text).'?=';
    }

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL .
    "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL .
    'From: '.adopt($project_name).' <lianaza@mail.ru>' . PHP_EOL .
    'Reply-To: lianaza@mail.ru' . PHP_EOL;

    mail($admin_email, adopt($form_subject), $message, $headers );
```

Comment: покажите как Вы получаете `$admin_email` и остальные переменные для письма

Comment: поправила в коде

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не учли одного, уже давно все используют SPF, DKIM, DMARC и прочие проверки валидности отправителя.
Когда вы пытаетесь отправить почту на mail.ru, он проверяет все заголовки, и отбрасывает ваше письмо, т.к. вы не прошли ни одну проверку. Поэтому даже в папке спам вы не нашли свое письмо!
Для теста можно отправить на любой почтовый сервер где нет подобных проверок.

В вашем случае нужно отправлять письма используя SMTP авторизацию на сервере.

Comment: примерно поняла,но на форуме нашла такои отзыв: Чтобы скрипт работал с mail.ru поменяйте в mail.php  отправителя. Mail.ru думает, что сами себе пишете! Например:
'From: '.adopt($project_name).' <ваш_текст>' . PHP_EOL .
'Reply-To: ваш_текст' . PHP_EOL;

Comment: поможет или бред?

Comment: @Лиана не поможет, там в любом случае должна быть DKIM подпись - которой у вас не будет.

Comment: Хорошо,спасибо,буду изучать эту тему!

Comment: так как нет времи все это изучать,сделала рассылку через почту хостинга и приходит на яндекс почту дубликаты писем)